# Checkbox is not being set

Tags: php, posting

isset not working. My goal is when the checkbox is checked I want to set a variable to a certain value but even when I check the checkbox the value of $mystring would be "no". Please let me know what I am doing wrong

```
<form class="cart" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="#">
<!--more code -->
<input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox"  />
<!--more code -->
</form> 
<?php
function my_add_cart_item_data( $cart_item, $product_id ) {
/* my problem is here */    
if ( isset( $_POST['mycheckbox'] )  ) {
    $mystring="yes";
 } else {
  $mystring="no";
 }
$cart_item['my_text'] = $mystring;
return $cart_item; 
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'my_add_cart_item_data', 10, 2 );     
?>
```

Comment: I don't know the woocommerce hooks but I'd be surprised if there wasn't a better way to add a custom field to a form. However I suggest you add `error_log( print_r( $_POST, true ) );` to the function temporarily, and then it'll a) dump out the contents of $_POST to your server or PHP error log so you can see what is or isn't there; and b) prove that this function is getting called at the expected time. Maybe dump out $cart_item and $product_id too. Hopefully that'll help show where the problem is!

Comment: I did as you suggested and the array returned the values correctly.